# Is possible to call jsp code line to servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have this line in jsp:

```
 <h1>Server hour:  <%= new java.util.Date() %> </h1>
```

my program is basic... I only want to change font and background color with servlet.. but I want to call jsp line here:

```
out.println("<html><body bgcolor="+backg+"> <font color="+ fontc +"> **HERE I WANT TO PUT MY LINE** </font> </body></html>");
```

this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
out.println("<html><body bgcolor=" + backg + "> <font color=" + fontc + "> <h1>Server hour:" + new java.util.Date() + " </h1></font> </body></html>");
```

Comment: NICE!!!!.... ONE FINAL QUESTION... IF I DONT WHANT TO BACKGROUND ALL BODY,, HOW CAN I DO TO ONLY BACKGROUND TEXT?

Comment: Change <h1>  to <h1 style='background:red;'>

Comment: but the backround sets with <select> tag, that's my application do. so I cant implement a static color. This is because I have <body bgcolor=" + backg + ">, but body bg color, background all page

Comment: If you want a dynamic text background then use another variable.  ... <h1 style='background:" + backText + ";'> ...

Comment: This is on servlet no?

Comment: so I delete this tag <body bgcolor=" + backg + "> and replace for this: <h1 style='background:" + backText + ";'>  but where I put my variable backg?

Comment: You can one variable for body background color and another one for the text background.

Comment: I don't want to use body background, but I can't it functionally, I don know why

Comment: I think you should compose a new question.